# Associating objects through primitive fields instead of aggregation

Tags: java, class, object, oop, aggregation

I know much about C#. This semester I am teaching Java, and I am not sure about what to show students about associating classes (or objects). I have read about association aggregation and composition in Java but they did not answer my specific question. In the last week, I may teach about Hibernate (as an ORM) and I feel like how we associate objects may play some role when transitioning to Hibernate. This was the case for me when I used EntityFramework as an ORM tool in C# case.

Let me explain my question through an example. I have Album and Song classes. An Album can have multiple Song objects. I can achieve this by containing the Song objects in an array. Below is how I do it:

```
public class Album{
    private int id;
    private Song[] songs;
    public Album(size, id){
        this.id = id;
        songs = new Song[size];
    }
}

public class Song{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public Song(int id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Another alternative is possible through a field (`albumId`) inside Song that indicates the associated album. Below are the Class designs:

```
public class Album{
    private int id;
    public Album(){
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class Song{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int albumId;

    public Song(int id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAlbum(int albumId){
        this.albumId = albumId;
    }
}
```

I consider the second alternative simpler and easier to grasp. At least it does not require to contain objects inside another. However, I do not know if it is a bad practice. I appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: I think the first version is idiomatic Java and should be preferred, although I'd use a `ArrayList` rather than an array.  The second version looks like a direct copy of a database implementation, and usually we don't like to see implementation details leaking through into other layers like you have here.

Comment: (I think the second implementation contains a typo.  In the constructor of `Album`, where is the variable `songs` declared?  I think you intended to remove that line.)

Comment: @markspace it was an error. in the second case no need for the array. yes, I will use ArrayList in actual implementation. Thanks for the recommendation. So, I will go with the first approach. I believe these relationships will be mapped properly and automatically with Hibernate.

Comment: entities should somehow represent actual domain model, the assumption the song relates to the single album only seems to be wrong: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_(music), so in that particular case I would prefer the first option.

Comment: I'd upvote Andrey's comment a couple more times if I could.  Very good point about songs belonging to more than one album.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov you mean there might be cases where you prefer the second option?

Comment: If we are talking about Hibernate (not `DDD`), in the most cases people tend to add `@XXXtoMany` associations just to get a convenient getter method in parent entity and some advantages of using cascade options, however, from performance and reliability perspectives, `@XXXtoMany` associations are always pain in behind, and my preference is to avoid using `@XXXtoMany` associations if it is possible, regardless whether such associations look natural for particular domain or not.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use a bidirectional relationship. The Album knows the songs and the song know what album it is from. Also, it is better and easier, especially if you want to use JPA, to use a List.

You manage the objects and their relationships, let JPA manage the ids.

```
public class Album {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();

    public Album(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Song> getSongs() {
        return Collections.immutableList(songs);
    }

    public Album addSong(Song song) {
        if(song.getAlbum()!=null && !this.equals(song.getAlbum())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Song already belongs to "+songs.getAlbum() );
        }
        if(song.getAlbum()==null) {
            song.setAlbum(this);
            songs.add(song);
        }
        return this;
    }
}

public class Song {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private Album album;

    public Song(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Album getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }
    public void setAlbum(Album album) {
        this.album = album;
    }
}
```

Comment: _the song know what album it is from_ that's wrong (as several comments already pointed out) making a bidi relationship also wrong (besides the usual too-strong-coupling argument against any  bidi relation)

Comment: It isn't wrong, it is very much case dependent. It is always "it depends", such a generalization bidirectional is wrong helps no one.

Comment: The next thing "is it an album -> track -> song"? Who cares, the question was about how to do it, not semantics of an album management system and if the ubiquitous languange in the domain is correct.